# Overloading "+" operator for matrices C++

Tags: c++

Here is a simplified addition operator overload for matrices that I've wrote, but my IDE (Clion) does not recognise it when I'm trying to use it like this: `m1 = m2 + m3`, and says: "binary operator + can't be applied to the expressions of type 'Matrix' and 'Matrix' "

```cpp
Matrix& Matrix::operator += (Matrix& m1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_rows; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < m_cols; ++j)
            m_matrix[i][j] += m1.m_matrix[i][j];
    return *this;
}

Matrix& operator + (Matrix m1, Matrix& m2){ return m1+=m2; }
```

What do I have to fix here?

P.S. I have also defined custom copy and move constructors and an assignment operator:

```
Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& m1)
    : m_matrix{new double*[m1.rows()]},
      m_rows{m1.rows()},
      m_cols{m1.cols()}
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m1.rows(); ++i) {
        m_matrix[i] = new double[m1.cols()];
        for (int j = 0; j < m1.cols(); ++j)
            m_matrix[i][j] = m1.m_matrix[i][j];
    }
}

Matrix& Matrix::operator = (const Matrix& m1){
    Matrix matrix(m1.rows(), m1.cols());

    for (int i = 0; i < m1.rows(); ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < m1.cols(); ++j)
            matrix.m_matrix[i][j] = m1.m_matrix[i][j];

    for (int i = 0; i < m_rows; ++i)
        delete m_matrix[i];
    delete m_matrix;

    m_matrix = matrix.m_matrix;
    m_rows = m1.rows();
    m_cols = m1.cols();

    return *this;
}

Matrix::Matrix(Matrix&& m1) noexcept
    : m_matrix{m1.m_matrix},
      m_rows{m1.m_rows},
      m_cols{m1.m_cols}
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m1.m_rows; ++i)
        delete m1.m_matrix[i];
    delete m1.m_matrix;
    m1.m_rows = m1.m_cols = 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you taking the right hand side by non-const reference?

Comment: Probably missing `Matrix::` before `operator+`

Comment: You are aware that your `operator+` returns reference to local variable???

Comment: Off-Topic: you should check for both matrices having the same number of rows and columns!

Comment: @Amadeus Currently, it doesn't, since he takes the left hand side of operator by value which will make a copy (that could be pretty clever... if only he didn't return a reference to that local variable :( ).

Comment: You are overloading `operator +=` and trying to use it as `operator +`?

Comment: @Caninonos It is true,I did not noticed that

Comment: Apart from the reference problem - have you *declared* the `operator+` in the header file, too???

Comment: @Aconcagua no, I want `operator +` to be a non-member function. And I actually do check rows and cols equality, but I removed it here so it wouldn't distract

Comment: @SergeiGorskiy So that's the problem. It must be declared in the header file, too - see my answer...

Comment: BTW, the compiler-generated copy/move/assign/destructor would be perfectly usable if you use a standard class such as `std::vector` to manage your memory resource - look up the Rule of Zero, soon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just guessing, as you did not provide the header file... Can it be that you forgot to declare the operator+ in your header file?

```
class Matrix
{
    // ...
};
Matrix operator+ (Matrix m1, Matrix const& m2); // just declared, not implemented!
```

If so, you are able to use the operator only from within the Matrix implementation file (and only after the implementation), as it is simply not known elsewhere...

Have a look at my changes, too: really important, I don't return a reference any more; doing so would return m1 (result of operator += as reference), which is a local variable, so you get a dangling reference and undefined behaviour as soon as using it!

Additionally, you won't change m2, so you easily can pass it as const reference (provided you do the same change for your operator+= within class Matrix), this gives you more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

The first, your global operator + for Matrix should not return a refferece, bacause in that case you can write smth like this:

```
Matrix m1,m2,m3;
m1+m2=m3;
```

and this is ill formed.

Furthermore, I guess this `Matrix& operator + (Matrix m1, Matrix& m2){ return m1+=m2; }` is a returning m1 which is not a reference.

Also make sure you get all you operator arguments as const references.

Comment: Much worse problem: m1 is returned, which is a local variable, though (i. e. dangling reference, undefined behaviour)!

Comment: I hadn't spotted the reference return type, but I don't think `m1+m2=m3` is the main problem here, the dangling reference to a temporary sounds a lot more dangerous. As for the infinite recursion... I don't see why?